# MediaElement WP plugin doesn't work IE9

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

We're using the MediaElement.js plugin for WordPress, which works great in every browser except IE9 on Win.  I've thoroughly tested the audio player with mp3's, and it just won't play large files.

"native" plugin (HTML5) does nothing.

"silverlight" plugin in debug mode says the state is, "Opening...", but nothing happens.

"flash" plugin plays large mp3's only after downloading a large portion of the file.

Anyone have any fixes for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the slowness in Flash is caused by a Virtual PC interface.

So, the workaround is to edit mediaelement-and-player.js, bypassing the 'native' player for IE9 by putting it into 'shim' mode. Then, bypassing the 'silverlight' player for all IE (wasn't working in IE8 either).